# wars files get auto deleted after some days from tomcat server

Tags: docker, tomcat, java-8, war

Actually i am using tomcat in docker and our war file is mounted on another folder. There are four directory
in mounted folder one is war file , two java-script  folder and one manager-gui folder. War file and other java-script folder get deleted automatically but manager-gui is still there . I am using java 1.8 , tomcat 9.0 and docker server version ->1.13.1 (Base OS Kernel Version: 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64).

```
 ->security.proto13-Dec-2022 10:10:16.849 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-124] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/admin-manager]
col = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
->13-Dec-2022 10:10:17.653 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-208] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/dashboard]
->13-Dec-2022 10:10:19.848 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-185] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/linedashboard]
->13-Dec-2022 10:10:21.182 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-152] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [moep] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
->13-Dec-2022 10:10:21.182 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-152] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [moep] registered the JDBC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

changes rights to access system and create tomcat container again . Can anyone tell why it is happening and how I can resolve it ??

Answer (score 0):

Typically manager-ui is provided by the tomcat installation you use in the Docker Image. While your WAR is deployed (possibly) as part of another process, running (possibly) once the container is already created.

Comment: Yes, i deployed  the war only after the container is created, but the war are being deleted as soon as the application is running.

Comment: `14-Dec-2022 07:43:19.481 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-188] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/nf4up4twal47h.war]
14-Dec-2022 07:43:19.509 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-188] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/nf4up4twal47h.war] has finished in [28] ms`

Comment: `nf4up4twal47h.war`  This war is deployed only after that all the war and js folders are deleted from there.

Comment: Ummm... sounds to me like the container is being recreated, can you check if the id of the container changes? maybe you are in swarm mode and it is beind killed and recreated

Comment: CONTAINER ID||IMAGE||COMMAND||CREATED||STATUS||PORTS||NAMES
88cd93b8d566 ||tomcat:9.0.46-jdk8-openjdk ||"catalina.sh run" ||2 weeks ago ||Up 7 hours ||0.0.0.0:8032->8080/tcp ||docker-compose_web_1

Comment: If you see the container was created 2 weeks ago and I have not noted whether the container id is changing or not but now I am tracking it as well.

Comment: Then it is something else, but the point is docker won't do that... it is something being done by a process in your container. Can it be that the app is undeployed by some /manager command (in that case the war is deleted automatically btw, did you know? https://www.google.com/search?q=why+would+tomcat+delete+war+file&oq=why+would+tomcat+delete+war+file)

Comment: yes i know but question is here who is changing running application war file. How to find out.

Comment: I can only think of checking the logs files in tomcat to check when is the app being undeployed and try to figure out why at that specific time the app is being undeployed